# SQL requires aggregate function over singular value

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, aggregate-functions

I have table language that contains the columns country, name and percentage.

A sample set might look like this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| country |  name   | percentage |
+---------+---------+------------+
| usa     | english |         85 |
| usa     | spanish |         10 |
| usa     | german  |          5 |
| germany | german  |        100 |
+---------+---------+------------+
I want to get
+---------+---------+------------+
| country |  name   | percentage |
+---------+---------+------------+
| usa     | english |         85 |
| germany | german  |        100 |
+---------+---------+------------+

select country, name, max(percentage) from language group by country
```

Tells me that I need to put all but one columns into either a aggregation function or the group by.
If you put the name into the group by, you get the original table, since all pairs of country and name are unique.
Name should be a single specific value since there can only be one pair of country and maximum percentage, so there's nothing to compare it too and it's a string anyway.

I'm sure there's a simple way to resolve this, without doing any second select statements and joining tables and the like.

Comment: [Classic example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) of a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Comment: The question isn't how to solve it, the question is if you can solve it with a simple query similar to the one in the OP.

Comment: ... The simplest queries are in the linked answer.  You can't get out of a join/nested select of some sort on DB2.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. If you submit this as an answer I'll give you your shiny star.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[SQL query for finding representative rows in a table](//stackoverflow.com/q/375262/90527)", "[How to find the record in a table that contains the maximum value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/376518/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum percentage, use `row_number()`:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by percentage desc) as seqnum
      from language l
     ) l
where seqnum = 1;
```